# How to change navigation menu position in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Hello I want to have this menu under header:

[image]

Comment: Hi ,Please take the time to read to see [ask], We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to find and update the template handling this header and the menu output.

This template should contain the `wp_nav_menu()` method ([see](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)) with the selected menu parameters. This output the menu, so you need to change the position of that code somewhere else in the HTML to match your needs.

Note: this is if the menu is correctly WP managed, and so you can add/edit items from the backend appearance > menus section.

Note2: some theme output the menu using actions/filters. In this case, you need to find the PHP code attaching the menu output to the action/filter, see if there is an action/filter under the header that matches your needs, and change the method that output the menu hook.